# Streamlit app URL from Sagemaker gives Expired Auth Token. Request

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-sagemaker, streamlit, amazon-sagemaker-studio

I started a streamlit app on Sagemaker following [this](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/tree/main/aws_sagemaker_studio/streamlit_demo) and I am able to view the app in my browser, but anyone else using the link gets this :

```
Invalid or Expired Auth Token. Request a new presigned URL to continue using SageMaker.
```

How do I resolve this? The link looks like

```
https://<domain>.studio.<region>.sagemaker.aws/jupyter/default/proxy/<port>/
```

Comment: Are you operating within a VPC?

Comment: yes, is there a specific workaround for this kind of setup?

Comment: Was there a way to resolve the problem by any chance?